# After mmap(), write to returned address is OK, but read cause system crash.Why?

Tags: linux, crash, kernel, mmap, itanium

I want to share memory between two process.
After `mmap()`, I get a address  `mapStart`, then I add offset to `mapStart` and get `mapAddr`, and make sure `mapAddr` will not exceed maped PAGE_SIZE.
 When I write to `mapAddr` by

```
memcpy((void *)mapAddr, data, size);
```

everything is OK.

But when I read from `mapAddr` by

```
memcpy( &data, (void *)mapAddr, size);`
```

that will case system crash.
Who know Why?
[The similar problem is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733816/read-and-write-processs-memory-through-dev-mem-text-segment-works-but-data-se)

**Add some Info:**  @Tony Delroy, @J-16 SDiZ
mmap function is:

```
mapStart = (void volatile *)mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, memfd, pa_base);
```

system crash: have no any OS error message, Console print some `MCA` info

the detail described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733816/read-and-write-processs-memory-through-dev-mem-text-segment-works-but-data-se)

Comment: Here's a crazy idea - why don't you show the code preparing arguments for `mmap()`?  In all probability the protection flag's lacking `PROT_READ`, but how could we tell?

Comment: what kind of "system crash"? sigfault? kernel panic? Give the error message.

Comment: You mentioned IA64 in other post, is this the same arch?

Comment: yeah, actually these two problem is one problem, both in IA64

Comment: There are a few MCA related bugs. if you can (1) reproduce this without a kernel module (ie, this is not your bug); (2) reproduce this on other hardware (ie, this is not a hardware problem), go and ask on `linux-ia64@vger.kernel.org`.

Comment: 1) What is data (how big is it) ? 2) what is size? 3) what is pa_base ?

Comment: @wildplasser, I will read  a long; size is 8; pa_base is a physical address aligned PAGE_SIZE, you could check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733816/read-and-write-process-memory-through-dev-mem-text-segment-works-but-data-seg)

Comment: see my answer for a wild guess

Answer (score 1):

Just some idea.

Is your `mmap()` spanning over memory regions with different attribute? This is illegal. 
Older kernel (you said 2.6.18) allowed this, but crash when you write to some of it.

See [this post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.ia64/16211/) for some starting point. If it is possible, try a newer kernel.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible issues:

> After mmap(), I get a address mapStart, then I add offset to mapStart and get mapAddr, and make sure mapAddr will not exceed maped PAGE_SIZE.

Not `mapAddr` must be made sure not to exceed the mapped size, but `mapAddr+size`. You are trying to touch `size` bytes, not just one.

```
memcpy((void *)mapAddr, data, size);
memcpy( &data, (void *)mapAddr, size);
```

Assuming `data` is not a array (which is a plausible assumption since you use it without address operator in the first line), the second line copies **not** from the location *pointed to* by data, **but** starting with data. This is quite possibly some unallocated memory, or some location on the stack, or whatever. If there is not a lot on the stack, it might as well read beyond the end of the stack into the text segment, or... something else.

(If `data` is indeed an array, it is of course equivalent, but then your code style would be inconsistent.)

Comment: First:I can make sure `mapAddr+size`(program tested) will not exceed the mapped size. Second: data is long type, and size is 8, so I think that will not cause problem.

Comment: "Second: data is long type" -- in that case, `&data` is the address of data, and the reason for the crash is exactly as I told you. You read "some undefined memory range" starting from the address of data. Remove the address-of operator (`&`), also you want to use a pointer for where a pointer is needed. Using `long` for pointers kind of works in C because C isn't so strict with types, but it's technically wrong. A pointer and an integer (or `long` if you will) are not the same things.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am sorry that should have no `&`, it's my mistake. but remove '&' still could not resolve problem. And I also tried `printf("%ld", (long)(*(long*)mapAddr));` that caused system crash too, I use `memcpy()` just because it looks a formal read.

Comment: And, I think If my program access "some undefined memory range", normally, it will cause a segment error, and program will crash and exit. But my situation is system directly Crash without any log message, but only have console output that is MCA info.